# Why my code not working? to find a word before the match

Tags: python, regex

```
s = 'A boy is playing and he is wearing shirt.'
```

My regex is `((?:\S+\s+)\bis\b)`

My output: `['boy is' ,'he is']`

Expected output: `['boy','he']`

Comment: just change the capuring group to inner like this -> (?:(\S+\s+)\bis\b)

Comment: regex, \S+(?=\s+is\b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your regex to use a lookahead:

```
\S+(?=\s+is\b)
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/NfBWwJ/1)

In python

```
import re

s = 'A boy is playing and he is wearing shirt.'
print(re.findall(r'\S+(?=\s+is\b)', s))
```

Output:

```
['boy', 'he']
```

Comment: Small suggestion. You can use raw string to avoid double escaping i.e. `re.findall(r'\S+(?=\s+is\b)', s)`

Answer (score 3):

You may reorganize your capture group a bit to keep `is` word outside the group and use `re.findall`:

```
>>> s = 'A boy is playing and he is wearing shirt.'
>>> re.findall(r'(\S+)\s+is\b', s)
['boy', 'he']
```

`findall` returns only captured group, if there is any in your regex.

Also note that there is no need to use `\b` (word boundary) after matching whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

To keep the solution closest to what you got earlier, you could `replace` the `'is'` with `''` and then strip off any white space left, using a list comprehension on the `re.findall` result.

```py
import re

s = 'A boy is playing and he is wearing shirt.'
[x.replace('is','').strip() for x in re.findall('\s*([a-zA-Z+]*\s+is)', s)]
```

**Output**:

```
['boy', 'he']
```

Comment: It will give wrong result if input is `s = 'A boy is playing and he is wearing his shirt.'`

Comment: @anubhava Thank you for pointing it out. Changed `'...\s*is)'` to `'...\s+is)'` to take care of it.

Comment: ok good but why use `.replace` and `.strip` when it can be done with just `findall`

Comment: Agreed. `findall` alone can do that. But I wanted to show if you start with the result `['boy is', 'he is']`, how you could extract `['boy', 'he']` with list-comprehension. It is not a better solution over `findall`, but is a solution at-least. The point is sometimes, one may not have the correct `regex` pettern and that could lead to a similar situation. I wanted to highlight how one could think getting around such a situation.